# Cell functions for nested cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I would like to know if it is possible to use cell functions in nested cell arrays.

Let's say I have a  3x3 cell array AB, each element of which is again a 3x3 cell array and each element of which is then for example a 3x3 matrix.

```
   A=cell(3,3);
   AB=A;
   for i=1:1:3
      for j=1:1:3
          AB{i,j}=cell(3,3)
      end
   end
```

If I then want to do an operation in each matrix, and thus in each element of each element of the cell array (sorry it sounds horrible), how would it work?

An example would be, if you want to build the sum of the matrix rows, with something like this...

```
    AB2=cellfun(@sum,AB);
```

or

```
    AB2=cellfun(@sum,AB{:,:});
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried multiple combinations with anonymous functions but they didn't work either. 
Is there a way to do this or do I need to put the cellfun in a loop?

I would appreciate your help.

Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellfun` will work if you have an unnested cell array, i.e. a single level of cells. For example, if you define your array as a 3×3×3×3 cell array of matrices you just need

```
result = cellfun(@(x) sum(x,1), AB, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

If you really need to do it a cell array of cell arrays of matrices, you can nest two `cellfun`. This will be slow:

```
result = cellfun(@(ab) cellfun(@(x) sum(x,1), ab, 'uniformoutput', false), AB, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

I'm using `sum(x,1)` to get the sum of each matrix *column*. If you want the sum of each *row* replace `1` by `2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!
I have tried with the first option and it works, but I need to continue operating with the second part of the cell array - let's say for cell array `{a,b,c,d}` - with elements in c and d. If I want to convert this into a matrix for the following operations with `cell2mat` I guess I need to keep the shape of the nested cell array and I can apply your second option (with two nested `cellfun`) with `cell2mat` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the 2nd option is slower, is there any other way of doing this? Or is there a way of converting c and d into a matrix keeping `{a,b}` as cell array containing `[c,d]` when the cell array has the form `{a,b,c,d}`?
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Anna I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Perhaps a small numerical example would help

Comment: Sorry for that, maybe this helps understand what I mean:  
    `A1=cellfun(@(ab) cellfun(@(x) sum(x,1), ab, 'uniformoutput', false), AB, 'uniformoutput', false); %A1{a,b}{c,d}[1,1], AB=A{a,b}{c,d}[1,30]`
    `A2=cellfun(@cell2mat, A1, 'uniformoutput', false); %A2{a,b}[c,d] `
    `A3=cellfun(@sum, A2, 'uniformoutput', false); %A3{a,b}[c,1] `   
    `B1= cellfun(@(x) sum(x,1), AB, 'uniformoutput', false); %B1{a,b,c,d}`      
B2...? How would you reshape B2 to have the form{a,b}[c,d] so that you can do other operations?